# How to highlight active item in custom taglist on shopify collection page

Tags: collections, tags, filtering, customization, shopify

I've added custom tags to my collection pages with help from this support forum: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/change-order-in-which-tags-are-displayed-on-collection-page-179468

The tags that appear on the collection pages are defined by linklists in the navigation. There is more about this in the discussion forum I posted above.

The snippet of code I inserted into collection-template.liquid just below the header is:

```
{% capture collection_taglist %}{{ collection.handle | append: "-tags" }}{% endcapture %}
{% if linklists[collection_taglist] %}
  <ul class="tags tags--collection inline-list">
    {% for link in linklists[collection_taglist].links %}
    <li>{{ link.title | link_to: link.url }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
```

Everything is working as intended, however I cannot get the active tag to be highlighted using CSS styling. I also tried some Javascript (see below) but that does not seem to be working either.

```
jQuery(".tags").find("a[href='"+window .location .href+"']").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
});
```

See here: http://shopsexologyinstitute.com/collections/women (you can enter using the password 'eaclim')

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into this in all sorts of circumstances. Running the following in the console outlines the issue:

```
jQuery(".tags").find('a').each(function(){ console.log(this.href);});
```

The host in the urls is not the host of the site.

You'll need to extract the pathname for comparison. There are various ways to do that but run the following in Chrome or Firefox to get the idea. URL is not widely supported so for production you'd need a different way to parse the link urls:

```
(function(){
    var path = location.pathname;
    return jQuery(".tags").find('a').filter(function(){
        console.log('checking: '+ this.getAttribute('href'));
        var href = new URL(this.getAttribute('href'), location.href);
        console.log(href.pathname +' vs '+ path);
        return href.pathname  == path;
    });
})();
```